# What does "if not" mean here?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
 def santa(*says):
    if not says:
        return "ho! xmas!"
    else:
        return says[0]+"! "+santa(*says[1:])
```

This is a recursive function with positional argument syntax that has troubled my understanding. What does "`if not says`" mean? Is it equal to "`if says == False`"? Or "`if says is None`"? Because if I substitute it with either of both, it gives an error.

How does it link to:

`print(santa())`

which has no arguments and outputs

```
"ho! xmas!"
```

meaning that it satisfies the first conditional statement.

Comment: if `says` is *falsy* i.e. an empty tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically checking whether `says` has any value. An if check on an object checks for the truth value of that object. `says` will be a tuple here. Tuples are `True` in an if check if they have any values. So in effect this is checking if `says` is (`not`) non-empty.

The docs have more details if you're interested: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html

Answer (score 0):

```
def santa(*says):
    if not says:
        return 'ho! xmas!'
```

So what we have here is a function definition that accepts an arbitrary list of inputs.  The first thing the function is doing is checking if the list is empty.  It then returns a formatted phrase, ending the function.

You probably already know this, but an if statement checks the result of a boolean statement and sets the program flow accordingly.  In this case, the boolean statement is `not says`. `says` is the arbitrary list being passed to the function.  Since every object in Python has a boolean result, `says`, being a list object, has a boolean result.  If it's empty, the result is `false`.  If it isn't empty, the result is `true`.

So `if not says:` will go on the `true` path if `says` is empty, due to the `not` qualifier, and the `false` path if `says` isn't empty.

More about Python truthiness can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

In Python, an empty tuple evaluates to `False` in a boolean context. This can be seen by casting an empty tuple to a boolean value:

```
>>> says = ()
>>> bool(says)
False
>>>
```

That means the statement `if not says` is testing if any arguments were passed into the function via `says` using the `not` operator. Here is an example:

```
>>> says = ()
>>> not says
True
>>>
```

So when you call `santa()` without any arguments, the first `if` statement evaluates to `True`, and `"ho! xmas!"` is returned.

Comment: So why would `if says == False` give an error? Aren't they the same thing

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo It shouldn't give an error, but it also shouldn't work either.  When you do `if says`, it is equivlent to doing `if bool(says)`. Python automatically converts `says` to a boolean yourself. However, when you try to test if `says` is "falsy" yourself, Python also expects you to covert `says` to a boolean. That is why `if says == False` doesn't work.